# nuget: No packages found

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I have the latest Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS with mono-runtime installed. I have installed the nuget package with apt but it is unable to see any packages.

```
nuget list -Verbosity detailed
```

gives this error message:

```
WARNING: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)
No packages found.
```

and

```
nuget install Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Verbosity detailed
```

returns with this:

```
WARNING: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)
WARNING: An error occurred while loading packages from 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/': Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'.
  at NuGet.PackageRepositoryHelper.ResolvePackage (IPackageRepository sourceRepository, IPackageRepository localRepository, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) <0xb459aea8 + 0x001fb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.PackageRepositoryHelper.ResolvePackage (IPackageRepository sourceRepository, IPackageRepository localRepository, System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) <0xb459ae10 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage (System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) <0xb459ada8 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.Commands.InstallCommand.InstallPackage (IFileSystem fileSystem, System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version) <0xb4a844f0 + 0x001f5> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.Commands.InstallCommand.ExecuteCommand () <0xb4a830c0 + 0x0014f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.Commands.Command.Execute () <0xb4a99878 + 0x0029c> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0xb71dc910 + 0x004c2> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Could somebody please point me where to start debugging? I am browsing the net for almost two hours but I couldn't come up anything useful for this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/MonoDevelop-4-2-3-Web-Service-Client-Exception-Error-SendFailure-Error-writing-headers-at-System-Neta-td4663279.html

Comment: Thanks, Zacharee1. I don't know whether that certificate issue is related and if it is, I can't find any lead how I could use the info there. I thought nuget would work out of the box. Unfortunately it is only very minimally documented. It doesn't even have a 'man' entry. :(

Comment: Hmm. Well what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644193/install-package-microsoft-owin-host-systemweb-fails